# Grails 2.3.8 RESTful API

Tags: rest, grails

I am using Grails 2.3.8 on a Mac.

I hope to use Grails to quickly develop a RESTful API. I started with the basic documentation for Web Services, found here for my version:
http://grails.org/doc/2.3.8/guide/webServices.html#domainResources

This seems to suggest that I can create a simple Domain Class in Grails, then annotate with the @Resource from grails.rest, as follows (straight from the docs above):

```
import grails.rest.*

@Resource(uri='/books', formats=['json', 'xml'])

class Book {

    String title

    static constraints = {
        title blank:false
    }
}
```

When I place this file into the grails-app/domain directory and run the app, the docs suggest I should be able to use cURL to add "Book" objects via HTTP:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"title":"Along Came A Spider"}' localhost:8080/myapp/books
```

But this gives me HTTP 422, with the following message:

```
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 05 Aug 2014 01:46:05 GMT

{"errors":[{"object":"Book","field":"title","rejected-value":null,"message":"Property [title] of class [class Book] cannot be null"}]}
```

Can anyone advise as to what I am missing here? I expected this to be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Defect in 2.3.8: [https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11399](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11399), either upgrade to 2.3.9 or downgrade to 2.3.7

Comment: Confirmed! Upgrading to latest (2.4.3) fixed the problem. Feel free to add as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @raffian mentioned above in comment, this was due to a bug in Grails 2.3.8:

https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11399

Upgrading resolved the issue.